# SetAdapter on a SherlockFragmentActivity? (Nullpointerexception)

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have a custom Listview that I want to try and implement in my SherlockFragment(Tab1).

In a normal extend activity it works great, but whenever I try and declare it in my SherlockFragmentActivity(MainActivity) - I get a **NullPointerException.**

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       RecipeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
       adupter = new MainListCustomBaseAdapter(ShoppingItems, this);
       RecipeList.setAdapter(adupter);

    //Deploying a listener menu
       registerForContextMenu(RecipeList);

 {
```

My FragmentTab1:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

@Override
public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
    return super.getSherlockActivity();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scanlist, container, false);



    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);
}



}
```

And my customlistviewAdapter:

```
public class MainListCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    static ArrayList<ListItems> DataSomething;
    static Context Cont;

    public MainListCustomBaseAdapter (ArrayList<ListItems> shoppingItems, Context c){
        DataSomething = shoppingItems;
        Cont = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DataSomething.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DataSomething.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = convertView;


         if (v == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)Cont.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mainlistlayout, null);
         }

         else{

            return v; 

         }


           ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ListImage);
           TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);

           ListItems msg = DataSomething.get(position);
           image.setImageResource(msg.icon);
           titleView.setText(msg.title);


        return v;

    }

    public void updateResults(ArrayList<MainListCustomBaseAdapter> results){
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


}
```

And the error looks like this:

```
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.com.barcoder/org.example.com.barcoder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at org.example.com.barcoder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
08-08 16:25:45.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2621):     ... 11 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I cant figure it out.. for the life of me.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FragmentTab1 - scanlist.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**  This thing was FIXED! Thank you kindly, Talklol for getting me thinking the right way.

Comment: What's on line 74 of MainActivity.java ?

Comment: RecipeList.setAdapter(adupter);

Comment: RecipeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView) returns null. This means findViewById did not find your list view. Are you sure your ID is correct? Try to clean your project too..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have cleaned, and cleaned and restarted eclipse time and again, but the same problem comes up.

Comment: Can you paste activity_main.xml ? btw, where is your FragmentTab1 referenced, I can't see it used anywhere

Comment: Sure, the code has been updated. Just to be clear, I want the listview to show up in the fragmenttab1. Could that have been something I missed? If so, how do I declare a custom listview in a SherlockFragment?

Comment: Update: I got it working! Thanks Talklol you made me find the correct answer! I owe you a beer! If you post a nonsensepost Ill give you the right answer as a thanks! Again a billion thanks. (solution: I had to declare the listview in the fragment and then use the getactivity() as an argument!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's one thing better than finding the solution for you, is helping you figure it out yourself. Good job!

> Update: I got it working! Thanks Talklol you made me find the correct answer! I owe you a beer! If you post a nonsensepost Ill give you the right answer as a thanks! Again a billion thanks. (solution: I had to declare the listview in the fragment and then use the getactivity() as an argument!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the else part in the getView method of your adapter. The values for the views should be set irrespective of whether it has been inflated previously or should be inflated for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Removing the else argument will produce the exact same error, however.

Answer (score 1):

As Talkol pointed out in his comment, RecipeList is probably null. I cant see view with id `mainListView` in `activity_main.xml` so `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView)` will return null;

Comment: Thanks Lecho, I figured it out. Turns out that I had to declare the customlistview in the Sherlockfragment and use getactivity() instead of this, as an argument! Much obliged.